# Rcpp: "Cannot change working directory" when called with embedded R code

Tags: r, rstudio, rcpp

I have been successfully using `Rcpp` for a while, and have been able to experiment with most of its features. However, on a Windows 7 machine, with RStudio 0.98.1049 I am not able to `sourceCpp` a file that has embedded R code chunks in it.

Here is M(N)WE:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double plusOne(double x) {
  return x + 1.0;
}


/*** R
plusOne(3)
*/
```

When I `sourceCpp(..., embeddedR = TRUE)`, I get this error message:

> Error in setwd(rWorkingDir) : cannot change working directory

which I am guessing arises from line 181 [here](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/master/R/Attributes.R). Not sure how to fix this. I am able to change directories from RStudio in general.

Comment: This issue should have been fixed with the latest version of Rcpp -- are you using 0.11.3?

Comment: @KevinUshey Updating now. Was on 0.11.2.

Comment: @KevinUshey Cool, that works. Make an answer and you have the points. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was resolved with Rcpp 0.11.3 -- it should go away if you update.